# D3 v7 join pattern enter update and exit not working neither with key function?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I am doing a project with Angular and d3js v7 where we create a dashboard plenty of charts. These charts have to be updated in real time, so we have to develop reusable chart that really only change what is it updated in the data without redrawing everything.

The problem when I use

join( enter => (enter. ...), update => (update. ...), exit => exit. ...)

pattern, is that seems to work well when entering new nodes. But, even if I indicate through a key function the identifier in the dataset, any time there is an update it gets all the nodes

I do a dummy and vanilla example, in which we can visually appreciate without debugging that all nodes appear to be updating instead of the last one.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d3js-ieurrt?file=index.html,index.js,package.json

**First time entering new nodes and empty updates**

[image: First time entering new nodes and empty updates]

**Second time not entering new nodes that it is ok, but empty updates with all of them!!!**

[image: Second time not entering new nodes but updates with all of the nodes]

What, I am doing wrong?

Any helps would be really appreciated.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: You are giving too much credit to the `update` selection.  It is simply **all** the elements already bound to data.  It is not "smart" enough to track changes within the data of an already bound element.

Comment: Exactly!!! I figured it out days ago, after several debuggings and simplifying to the most basic examples...I can imagine there a lot of people confused as I was, I love your definition and I feel more confident that someone can confirm it for me as well. Many Thx!!!